# Tomcat HTTP access before it fully started

Tags: java, tomcat

I use Tomcat to run two web applications, lets call it "configserver" and "rest".

When "rest" starts it should call "configserver" on the same Tomcat via HTTP. Unfortunately I found out that already started "configserver" doesn't response on any HTTP requests before Tomcat is fully started. In the same time Tomcat cannot be fully started before "rest" get configuration from "configserver".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view would be a change of design required. Such tight coupling can only give issues.

I would suggest; the rest server has a default/fallback configuration that it uses in the event it cannot reach the configserver, and that the restserver polls the configserver every X period.

Comment: Rest is already polling "configserver" every X period, but during this "rest" cannot be defined as "deployed" and it means tomcat is not fully started.

Comment: BTW, regarding coupling, these applications gets information about each other via service discovery.

Comment: I would look at a fallback configuration of some sort, you would need an saved config state anyway in case of a bad response when running.

Comment: In my case if config server returns bad response application should be stopped (or failed).